# Mode Rewrite is not working for one address

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have added into htaccess file some rules in order to remove index.php from the url in Code Igniter . However, for just one address it is not working

the url is like this "http://example.com/subtitle/eveythingelse/";

so when the second uri is "subtitle" or "sub" it doesn't send to "index.php" and directly reads the folder which doesn't exist.

if I change the second uri "http://example.com/changed/everythingelse" it works.

I am really confused about.

this is code of .htacce :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because with final /

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Test if the directory exist, and don't do rewrite.
You can delete this condition.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted one .php file in the root directory and it worked. it seems that there was a conflict because that file has the name "subtitle" in part of it.